# How can I check my ajax application and site on multiple browsers?

Tags: browser

I am running windows 7 which won't even allow me to use the latest IE version for testing.

I currently use google crome and firefox.  Is there a program or easy way to test a site with multiple browsers, and not just

the way they might look but everything like javascript and ajax just as if I were using that particular browser?

Comment: it won't let you use the latest IE version? wtf

Comment: Ya when I go to install it, it says something like "This IE version is not supported on your OS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.xenocode.com/Browsers/ has some great online browser virtualizations.

They take a bit to load but are perfect for testing. Javascript and such will work like normal and you can try out all the versions of IE from the same computer without installing anything.

I should note that these launch fully functional browser windows- It is not an in browser preview type thing.

They used to have multiple IE versions, Firefox, Opera and safari available to download as portable software but I can't find them anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Install a virtual machine manager - OpenBox from Sun is free and works OK - and install a copy of Windows / Linux / whatever in each of a bunch of virtual machines. Then in each Windows either keep the installed browser (ie IE 6, hahah, in XP) or upgrade it to IE 7 or IE 8. Also install whatever versions of FF and Opera and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but I get by using [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) for different versions of IE.  The author claims it works on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [TestSwarm](http://testswarm.com/), by John Resig. His blog article on here is at:
http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-testing-does-not-scale/